# DIV:hover changes attributes of another DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the attributes of one `div` from another `div`'s hovering. Both of the div's has their own unique ID and I'm wondering if this is possible.

Here is the jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ngx5D/

And here is the sample code:

```
body {
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

#div_one, #div_two{
    background-color:darkred;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px;
    margin:10px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;  
}

#div_one:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write like this:

```
#div_one:hover + #div_two{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Ngx5D/1/

Comment: Let me send this as a non-working 3-element example where I want to modify div_three by hovering div_one: http://jsfiddle.net/37KuM/

Comment: Oh here is a weird situation I've just discovered:
http://jsfiddle.net/6THpF/

Should I open another thread to get answers for this one? (div one can modify div2, but vica-versa doesn't work!)

Comment: You can't never go against the flow in CSS. No parent selector, no previous sibling selector. To do so, you have to use JavaScript.